# Editing a config file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, ini, toml

I am building a program that edits a ***.toml config*** file, take this for example:
This is one of the sections from the entire .toml config file:

```
[APU]
apu = "any"                   # Audio system. Use: [any, nop, sdl,xaudio2]
```

Normally the users changes the options manually for example if they want to change the apu they just replace the any inside quotation marks ("") with xaudio2 for example.

I want to create a code which presents the setting (apu = " "), and the options that the user has (any,xaudio,nop...)
and let the user choose between the options.

This was the code I originally wrote:

```
f = open("config.toml", "r")
fread = f.read()

### APU Options ###
nop = fread.replace('apu = "any"', 'apu = "nop"')
sdl = fread.replace('apu = "any"', 'apu = "sdl"')
xaudio2 = fread.replace('apu = "any"', 'apu = "xaudio2"')


### Write the New File ####
with open("config.toml", "w") as f:
    f.write(xaudio2)
```

this code lacks something, when a user changes the apu to xaudio2 with this exact code, after the user re opens the program(this python code) for changing the apu again , the python code can not detect the original code since it **was**:

```
apu = "any"
```

and now **after** the user has changed it to xaudio2 It will be this:

```
apu = "xaudio2"
```

the python code looks only for the apu = "any" to change and replace any with other options.
What do you think is the solution? (when one of the settings in the config changes)

Comment: Use something like https://pypi.org/project/toml/? Or if using python 3.11. there is a standard library already included

Comment: You probably want to use `tomllib`', it's in the standard library, and it allows you to access and modify the configuration file smartly.

Comment: I've already done some coding with the .toml project (I've just checked out tomllib too) but I don't think they can help, or maybe I'm wrong idk
What are you suggetiong to do with the .toml project? the only good thing it can do is to parse the file and make the sections, list-like rather than string